# cvFindContours is not producing the output I expect

Tags: c, opencv, image-processing

I have a simple, contrived example of finding connected components on a binary image using cvFindContours with the OpenCV C API. (This is part of a larger piece of software written in C, so using the C++ API is not an option.)

A sample input image consists of two filled, white squares on a black background that do not overlap. I would expect to get two contours out of this representing the connected components that make up the perimeter of each square. Instead I get four components. Why? Details below.

First I threshold my input image in 'self', which is a CV_32FC1 image with background pixels of 0.0 and white pixels (the two squares) of value 1.0:

```
cvThreshold(self, self, 0.8, 1.0, CV_THRESH_BINARY);
```

I then copy my input image to a CV_32SC1 image of the same size with cvScale:

```
CvMat * temp = cvCreateMat(height, width, CV_32SC1);
cvConvertScale(self, temp, 1, 0);
```

I then do cvFindContours to get connected components:

```
CvSeq * components = 0;
CvMemStorage * mem = cvCreateMemStorage(0);
cvFindContours(temp, mem, &components, sizeof(CvContour), CV_RETR_CCOMP, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, cvPoint(0,0));
```

I then do the following to output the points that make up the contours and draw them to a window.

```
for(; components != 0; components = components->h_next)
    {
        printf("===============NEW COMPONENT!============\n");
        if (components->v_next) printf("This has a child.\n");
        CvPoint * pt_array = (CvPoint *)malloc(components->total*sizeof(CvPoint));

        cvCvtSeqToArray(components, pt_array, CV_WHOLE_SEQ);
        for (int i = 0; i < components->total; i++)
        {
            printf("Point %i: %i, %i\n", i, pt_array[i].x, pt_array[i].y);
    }
    free(pt_array);
    outer_color = CV_RGB(rand()%255, rand()%255, rand()%255);
    cvDrawContours(dst, components, outer_color, inner_color, -3, 1, 8, cvPoint(0,0));
}
```

I would expect this to produce two contours representing the perimeter of the two white squares in my binary image. Instead, I get four top-level contours which are approximately right on top of each other. What gives?

The points in the four contours are as below:

```
===============NEW COMPONENT!============
Point 0: 200, 150
Point 1: 200, 199
Point 2: 199, 200
Point 3: 150, 200
Point 4: 149, 199
Point 5: 149, 150
Point 6: 150, 149
Point 7: 199, 149
===============NEW COMPONENT!============
Point 0: 150, 150
Point 1: 150, 199
Point 2: 199, 199
Point 3: 199, 150
===============NEW COMPONENT!============
Point 0: 50, 10
Point 1: 50, 49
Point 2: 49, 50
Point 3: 10, 50
Point 4: 9, 49
Point 5: 9, 10
Point 6: 10, 9
Point 7: 49, 9
===============NEW COMPONENT!============
Point 0: 10, 10
Point 1: 10, 49
Point 2: 49, 49
Point 3: 49, 10
```

Comment: Can you add the sample image to that and the intermediate images?

Answer (score 0):

A shot in the dark but i know that the contour methods flags control the result sets structure. Perhaps try swapping the CV_RETR_CCOMP flag with one of the flasg described [here](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/1.5.0.0/Help/html/95b2e17e-3891-d3e3-cbba-4a844b0cf874.htm).

This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8461612/using-hierarchy-in-findcontours-in-opencv) explains a bit as to how the flag CV_RETR_CCOMP works.

It is odd though, i wouldn't expect the results your getting either.