# OpenCV Crop Rectangle

Tags: python, opencv

UPDATE** tried adding some pieces of code that seem to make sense but still isn't giving me the desired effect.

Hello I'm interested in cropping **ALL OF** the contents of an image I was able to isolate using OpenCV's rectangle function. Once I do this I would like to be able to apply the cropped contents to a white background.

This is my original image

[image: 2]

The image I have been able to isolate using rectangles is below:

[image: 1]

The code I'm using so far is as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

im = cv2.imread('1.jpg')
im3 = im.copy()

gray = cv2.cvtColor(im,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray,(5,5),0)
thresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(blur,255,1,1,11,2)




contours,hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_LIST,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

squares = []

for cnt in contours:
    if cv2.contourArea(cnt)>50:
        [x,y,w,h] = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)

        if  h>28 and h<35:
            cv2.rectangle(im,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,0,255),2)
            cv2.imwrite('norm1.jpg',im)
crop_img = [[[255, 255, 255] for x in xrange(377)] for x in xrange(377) ] #newly added code starts here
for s in squares:
     s = squares[0]
     x = s[0]
     y = s[1]
     w = s[2]
     h = s[3]
     img = im[y:y+h,x:x+w]
          for col in range(y,y+h):
              for row in range(x,x+w):
                  if img[col - y][row - x].tolist() == [0,0,0]:
                      crop_img[col][row] = [0,0,0]


cv2.imwrite("cropped.jpg", np.array(crop_img))
```

The new code I added leads to this output.

[image: 3]

As seen in the code above I tried adding the coordinates of all the rectangles into an array and then tried to iterate and compile them onto a single image. Theoretically I thought this should work but it's not giving me the desired results. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To put it simple: contour that don't have a parent is an outer contour.

Answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8461612/using-hierarchy-in-findcontours-in-opencv) may help you to understand how this 'hierarchy' can be used. The code there is in C++, but it should be similar in Python.