# Discovering parent contours

Tags: c++, opencv

I have contours of my colored regions and keypoints returned from goodfeaturestotrack. At this moment there are points in the boundaries and points inside the contours. This is the result that i've been expecting. How can we discover the contours that are enclosing points inside? (First parent above)

I think that this can be done using hierarchy but i've never used it before.

Comment: are those contours extracted by canny+findContours (with flag to find not only external contours but all)? if not, provide sample images please

Comment: Hello @Micka. Yes, i have all the contours.

Comment: so your question is "how to test whether a point/pixel is inside of a contour"? afair there is some "isPointInContour" function but Im not 100% sure. But you can always draw a contour filled on black background an test for a point whether that mask is set for that position

Comment: Thks. I'm gonna try it :)

Answer (score 1):

Firstly if you use `cv::findContours`, it can return **heirarchy**: good description can be found in [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#findcontours) or in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8461612/using-hierarchy-in-findcontours-in-opencv).

You can also check each your point with `cv::pointPolygonTest` ([documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=pointpolygontest#pointpolygontest)): it checks whether the point is inside the contour.