# OpenCV cv::findcontours StackOverflow Exception

Tags: c++, opencv, rgb, contour, grayscale

I have a 3 channel cv::Mat (RGB 480 height by 640 width) and I want to find the contours of this picture.
I Tried different examples:
[This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8449378/finding-contours-in-opencv)
[This one](http://opencvexamples.blogspot.com/2013/09/find-contour.html#.U4HbFvldWSo)
But every time I get a stackoverflow error in the line:

```
cv::findContours(contourOutput, contours, CV_RETR_LIST, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);
```

or

```
cv::findContours(image, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, cv::Point(0, 0));
```

I paid attention to the size of the cv::Mat involved and to the number of channels of them. I don't know what else to do.
After few operations, my code is this one, and i always get the stack overflow in findcontours.

```
                cv::Mat src_gray;
                cv::Mat dst;
                cv::Mat canny_output;
                std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point> > contours;
                std::vector<cv::Vec4i> hierarchy;

                cvtColor(src, src_gray, CV_BGR2GRAY);

                int threshold_value = 0;
                int threshold_type = 3;
                int max_BINARY_value = 4;
                threshold(src_gray, dst, threshold_value, max_BINARY_value, threshold_type);


                /// Detect edges using canny
                Canny(dst, canny_output, 100, 100 * 2, 3);
                /// Find contours
                findContours(canny_output, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, cv::Point(0, 0));
```

What I obtain is: ***An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in xxx.exe***

Comment: your Canny still uses the rgb src image as input, and your threshold goes nowhere (dst is never used)

Comment: Yeah, i noticed that and i corrected that, but it still doesn't work

Comment: exact error is still missing.

Answer (score 3):

The input to [`findContours()`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=findcontours#findcontours) must be a **single** channel image. You can't pass it a 3 channel BGR image.

The solution is to convert you input image to grayscale.
eg. `cvtColor( src, src_gray, CV_BGR2GRAY );`

Of course it doesn't have to be a grayscale image, you could extract and use any single channel from an image using [`split()`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#split) eg. Hue, Saturation, Value, B, G, R... etc.

Also, `findContours()` woks best with a **binary** input image, so you may want to threshold your single channel image before passing it to `findContours()`.