# how to create the OpenCV function findcontour in my opencvWrapper file in iPhone application based on working Python code

Tags: python, swift, opencv

I have integrated OpenCV in my iPhone app and managed to take a photo and then process it with the following code. Now I want to implement the findcontour function in order to get the contours and hierarchies as I would do this in Python (code below). Can anyone assist with this code?

```
// OpenCVWrapper.mm

@implementation OpenCVWrapper : NSObject

+(UIImage *)ConvertImage:(UIImage *)image {
cv::Mat mat;
UIImageToMat(image, mat);


cv::Mat median;
cv::medianBlur(mat, median, 3);

cv::Mat gray;
cv::cvtColor(median, gray, CV_RGB2GRAY);  //or use COLOR_BGR2GRAY

cv::Mat denoise;
cv::fastNlMeansDenoising(gray, denoise, 30.0, 7, 21);


//here I want to enter the converted Python code from below in order to get the largest contour of the image
//cv::findContours(denoise, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);


UIImage *binImg = MatToUIImage(contour);
return binImg;
}
@end
```

The Python code is:

```
image, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(denoise,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

contours = [(c, cv2.contourArea(c)) for c in contours]
# sort contours list by area, biggest first
contours = sorted(contours, key=lambda c: c[1], reverse=True)

cnt = contours[0]
img = cv2.drawContours(frame, cnt, 0, (0,255,0), 2)
```

I am actually not sure whether I can process the UIImage and then return the contour only (transparent background) so that I can overlay it to the video stream. This is the code from the ViewController using captureOutput:

```
func captureOutput(_ captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputSampleBuffer sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer!,
                   from connection: AVCaptureConnection!) {
    guard let uiImage = imageFromSampleBuffer(sampleBuffer: sampleBuffer) else { return }
    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {

        self.imageView.image = OpenCVWrapper.convert(uiImage) ///I am really not sure whether this is the right code to show the uiImage on top of the live stream. Have not really gotten to that issue as yet, but any assistance is welcome
```

Comment: This is neither Python nor Swift. But C++. Also, did you look for C++ contours examples?

Comment: the second one is Python, which I want to convert to C++ and the third one is Swift. Do you know of any suitable links for contours in C++?

Comment: My point is that you look for somebody providing you with C++. So tagging the two languages you do not need, but not the one you need, seems odd to me. And the official OpenCV documentation is full of tutorial code, including contours related ones.

Comment: Also, obviously searching here for c++ OpenCV contours yields a lot of examples.

Comment: yes, you got me there, I have no idea about C++ and I don't want to get stuck into it just for these few lines. But I followed your advice and found these links which were very helpful and will help me to future it out myself. http://opencvexamples.blogspot.com/2013/09/find-contour.html and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8449378/finding-contours-in-opencv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

actually, I figured it out. Here is the working solution:

```
//Find the contours. Use the contourOutput Mat so the original image doesn't get overwritten
std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point> > contours;
cv::Mat contourOutput = canny.clone();
cv::findContours( contourOutput, contours, CV_RETR_LIST, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE );

int largest_area=0;
int largest_contour_index=0;
// iterate through each contour.
for( int i = 0; i< contours.size(); i++ )
{
    //  Find the area of contour
    double a=contourArea( contours[i],false);
    if(a>largest_area){
        largest_area=a;std::cout<<i<<" area  "<<a<<std::endl;
        // Store the index of largest contour
        largest_contour_index=i;

    }
}

cv::Mat contourImage(canny.size(), CV_8UC3, cv::Scalar(0,0,0));
cv::Scalar color;
color = cv::Scalar(255, 0, 0);

cv::drawContours(contourImage, contours, largest_contour_index, color);
```